# Does Gottesman-Knill theorem apply with any computational basis input?

Tags: simulation, clifford-group, stabilizer-state, gottesman-knill

On Wikipedia, the [Gottesman-Knill theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottesman%E2%80%93Knill_theorem) is said to state the following:

> A quantum circuit using only the following elements can be simulated efficiently on a classical computer.
>
> 1. Preparation of qubits in computational basis states,
> 2. Clifford gates, and
> 3. measurements in the computational basis.

However, in my class it was said that the theorem applies when the input is the "all-zeroes" state $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$. Is it indeed true that the theorem applies if we instead input $| x \rangle$ for any $x \in \{0,1\}^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two constraints on preparations are equivalent in the presence of Clifford gates. More precisely, for any $x=x_1x_2\dots x_n\in\{0,1\}^n$, we can prepare $|x\rangle$ in $O(1)$ time using $$|x\rangle=X^{x_1}\otimes X^{x_2}\otimes\dots\otimes X^{x_n}|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$$
where $X=|0\rangle\langle 1|+|1\rangle\langle 0|$ is a Pauli, and hence a Clifford, gate.